# Define custom order by city

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to define a custom ORDERY BY city.

Something like this:

```
New York (255)
Paris (26)
Vien(15)
```

And then `ORDER BY city ASC`.

I've tried this query and it doesn't work:

```
SELECT count(id_item) as q, city FROM item GROUP BY city ORDER BY FIELD(city,'New York','Paris','Vien'), city ASC
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: count returns just 1 row or ans? you sure this query is correct? try without the count as in what comes as result

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Define `does not work`, its hard to understand what is not working

Comment: I would like return list city sorting asc, but i would like add some city on first,second and third place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    count(id_item) as q, 
    city 
FROM 
    item 
GROUP BY 
    city 
ORDER BY
    ( 
        CASE 
            WHEN city='New York' THEN 1
            WHEN city='Paris' THEN 2
            WHEN city='Vien' THEN 3
            ELSE 4
        END
    ) ASC,
    city ASC
```

Comment: @BCM : Np, glad to help

Comment: FIELD achieves the same thing in fewer words.

Answer (score 1):

The ORDER BY keyword sorts the records in ascending order by default. To sort the records in a descending order, you can use the DESC keyword. Try this -

```
SELECT count(id_item) as q, city FROM item GROUP BY city ORDER BY city;
```

For descending you can do something like this -

```
SELECT count(id_item) as q, city FROM item GROUP BY city ORDER BY city DESC;
```

To fetch the rows with own preferred order, the SELECT query would as follows:

```
SELECT 
    count(id_item) as q, 
    city 
FROM 
    item 
GROUP BY 
    city 
ORDER BY
    ( 
        CASE 
            WHEN city='New York' THEN 1
            WHEN city='Paris' THEN 2
            WHEN city='Vien' THEN 3
            ELSE 4
        END
    ) ASC,
    city ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `order by city='New York' desc, city='Paris' desc, city='Vien' desc, city`

or even `order by city in ('New York', 'Paris', 'Vien') desc, city` because those 3 are already on alphabetical order